# How can one move to a new screen after clicking done on the iPhone keyboard?

Tags: iphone, uiview, keyboard, action

I'm a new iPhone developer, so I'd really appreciate some guidance.

I've started off with something...but I don't know what to do from there.

```
    - (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    //hide keyboard
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    //after hiding the keyboard, call another method
    //which should display a UITableView

    return YES;
    }
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: For a simple way of navigating through UIViews, look at the UINavigationController. There are several other ways to do this too.

Comment: All of the tutorials I've found require buttons...and they mention using the Interface Builder which I don't think I should use for the purpose of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look the Apple developer documentation that cover the topics of ViewControllers and navigation.

This should get you started.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Pardon my newbie question, but you're saying that essentially to have a table just display in the middle of the screen (I aim to have two static elements, one at the top and one at the bottom), I need to be using a navigation controller?

Comment: Not at all. Your question states you want to move to a new screen after dismissing the keyboard. In order to navigate between screens or UIViews, you can use a variety of navigation techniques. One of the most suitable is the UINavigationController. Without understanding your exact requirements, it's difficult to give a precise answer.

Comment: Hmm...okay that helps a little bit.  I apologize if it isn't specific enough, but basically when I type into a textbox, I want to emulate a dropdown box which automatically populates (it grabs information from a server).  The functionality is kind of like google's suggestion box thing.  Basically, I thought I'd have to use an unbounded table to display this information...is that a little more clear?

Comment: Okay, that's *VERY* different from what I read your question to mean ;) You basically want an auto-complete style box? You can add UIViews to UIViews to build up a layer of views. You could basically create a new view and position it below the textField and populate it with the available options. Are you trying to implement a search style system? You should follow the existing patterns in iOS. This is usually a search box that presents options in a table view.